# Change "Low quality posts" to "Low quality answers" in the help center

Tags: bug, status-declined, review-queues, low-quality-posts, help-center

Following the [most recent change to the review queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369013/571958):

> Name change: Low quality posts → Low quality answers (Stack Overflow
> only)

But some pages in the help center still reference using the old name. The ones I found were the [general review queues page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reviews-intro), linking to [the specific queue's page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality).

Inside that page, there are again references to "Low-quality posts" instead of "answers", and some of the information is now just wrong, like:

> This may include:
>
> ***questions*** or answers that are very short, in the wrong language or
> gibberish.

Can this be changed to match the queue's new name and function?

Comment: I think that help center page is probably part of the set that's universal to all Stack sites, no?

Comment: @zcoop98: Correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [zcoop98's comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412080/change-low-quality-posts-to-low-quality-answers-in-the-help-center#comment871724_412080) suggests, both of the help center articles you linked (["What are review queues?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reviews-intro) and ["How do I use the Low quality posts queue?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality)) have the same text network-wide. Stack Overflow's help center doesn't have a site-specific override for either one – and it's unlikely we'd create one, unless the info on the network-wide version does not accurately describe how the queue works on SO.

Right now, [the latter help center article about the Low quality posts queue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality) already mentions the following (and has since August 2021):

> **Note:** On Stack Overflow, this queue is titled "Low quality answers", and exclusively handles answers. You will not see questions in this queue.

As such, I don't really see a pressing need to create site-specific overrides of these two help center articles just to change the name used to refer to this queue. (Creating a site-specific override of a help center page means that updates to the network-wide version of the article will not be automatically propagated to the site-specific version, so we'd need a compelling reason to do so.) As such, we're declining this request.